# How can I test if my connection pool is working in a correct way?

Tags: java, http, soap, testing, apache-axis

I'm implementing a SOAP client using Apache Axis 2. Since the SOAP client must handle heavy number of requests I am using a connection pool.

To do that I had to set a few transport layer configuration of my stub that was generated from a WSDL file:

```
stub._getServiceClient().getOptions().setProperty(HTTPConstants.REUSE_HTTP_CLIENT, Constants.VALUE_TRUE);

MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager connectionManager = new MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager();
connectionManager.getParams().setDefaultMaxConnectionsPerHost(MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOST);
connectionManager.closeIdleConnections(IDLE_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(connectionManager);

stub._getServiceClient().getOptions().setProperty(HTTPConstants.CACHED_HTTP_CLIENT, httpClient);
```

My client seems to be working just fine. However, I would like to know how can I test if the connection pool is working in a correct way (i.e. the created connections are only destroyed after the time defined by the IDLE_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT constant). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pseudo-code based on JUnit 3.x:

```
  setUp() {
    initialize connection manager;
    initialize connection by creating client;
  }

  tearDown() {
    close connection if necessary;
    close connection manager if necessary;
  }

  testConnectionOpen() {
    assert that connection is open;
    pause for time of idle connection timeout - 1 second;
    assert that connection **is still open**;
  }

  testConnectionClosed() {
    assert that connection is open;
    pause for time of idle connection timeout + 1 second;
    assert that connection **is closed**;
  }
```

Adding 1 second and subtracting 1 second should be adjusted depending on sensitivity of the connection manager.

Answer (score 0):

Write a testbed application which will make a large number of requests, and assert that the number of connections is never more than MAX_CONNECTIONS. You might be able to check on the latter by attaching jconsole or VisualVM to the process.

You could also look into using [Jakarta JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/) for generating load on the class/client, and then graphing out several datapoints (not sure how you'd gain access to number of client connections created, though).

Answer (score 0):

You can test it by changing the parameters

- NO_OF_THREADS
- POOL_SIZE
- ENABLE_CONNECTION_POOLING

---

```
/** number of concurrent searches */
private static final int NO_OF_THREADS = 20;

/** size of the http connection pool */
private static final int POOL_SIZE = 20;

/** enabling or disabling the connection pool */
private static boolean ENABLE_CONNECTION_POOLING = true;

/** close idle connection time in milliseconds
 * connections will be release if they are idle for this time */
private static int CLOSE_IDLE_CONNECTION_TIME = 1000;

public void test()
{
    init();

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<Thread>();
    for ( int i = 0; i < NO_OF_THREADS; i++ )
    {
        SimpleThread thread = new SimpleThread();
        thread.start();

        threads.add( thread );
    }

    for ( Thread t : threads )
    {
        try
        {
            t.join();
        }
        catch ( InterruptedException e )
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    logger.info( "************* Test Finish In *******************" + ( System.currentTimeMillis() - start ) + " ms" );
}

public void init()
{
    super.init();

    try
    {
        long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        stub = new Viva_x0020_external_x0020_API_x0020_for_x0020_partnersStub( endUrl );

        if ( ENABLE_CONNECTION_POOLING )
        {
            stub._getServiceClient().getOptions().setProperty( HTTPConstants.REUSE_HTTP_CLIENT, Constants.VALUE_TRUE );
            MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager connectionManager = new MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager();
            connectionManager.getParams().setDefaultMaxConnectionsPerHost( POOL_SIZE );
            connectionManager.closeIdleConnections( CLOSE_IDLE_CONNECTION_TIME );
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient( connectionManager );
            stub._getServiceClient().getOptions().setProperty( HTTPConstants.CACHED_HTTP_CLIENT, httpClient );
        }

        logger.info( "Connection Established in " + ( System.currentTimeMillis() - t1 ) + "ms" );
    }
    catch ( AxisFault e1 )
    {
        e1.printStackTrace();
        fail( "Error on creating the stub" );
    }

    logger.info( "Connection Initialized successfully" );
}

public class SimpleThread extends Thread
{
    public void run()
    {
        search();
    }
}

private static void search()
{
    logger.info( "$$$$$$$$$$$$$ Start the Search $$$$$$$$$$$$$$" );
    GetAirportConnections request = new GetAirportConnections();
    request.setAirportCode( "MTY" );

    GetAirportConnectionsResponse response = null;
    try
    {
        long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        response = stub.getAirportConnections( request, getUserCredentials() );
        logger.info( "Results Retrived in " + ( System.currentTimeMillis() - t1 ) + "ms" );
    }
    catch ( Exception e )
    {
        logger.error( "------------------------- Connection Timeout --------------------------" );
        e.printStackTrace();
        fail( e.getMessage() );
    }

    Airport[] airports = response.getGetAirportConnectionsResult().getAirport();
    logger.info("Number of airports : " + airports.length );
}
```

}

Comment: how does this test if connections are destroyed after the idle timeout?